# Models for multivariate time series with no feature that is known in future time points

Tags: time-series

I have and have only 3 columns in my dataset, which all are time series. I want to forecast one of them, and the other 2 are categorical, which are strongly correlated with the target and can be one-hot encoded into about 100 binary time series. The thing is I don't know the future values of these 2 columns so I can't feed them as features into most models/algorithms (XGBoost, GLMs, random forest, etc.). So far, I only learned 2 methods for forecasting all the (about 100) time series together: 1. Neural Networks 2. Vector ARMA model.

Is there any other reasonable approaches to this problem? I know I can forecast each of the non-target column independently using the rest of the columns as features and forecast the target.

Thanks a lot...!